# Erroneous Textmate hash pair completion when using new hash syntax in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, autocomplete, textmate

When trying to use the new hash syntax in Ruby 1.9.2 in a Ruby on Rails project, Textmate erroneously autocompletes the hash pair. For example,

```
title:    "My Book Title"
```

turns into

```
title:key => "value",
```

when pressing tab after the colon. How do I stop this functionality? I'm new to Textmate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is likely due to the fact that the Ruby bundle you are running hasn't been updated for 1.9. You can fix this by going into the Bundle Editor (Bundles > Bundle Editor > Show Bundle Editor), finding Ruby and then change the `Hash Pair – :key => "value"` Snippet to:

`${1:key}: ${2:"${3:value}"}${4:, }`

*(It might help to select "Snippets" from the Combo Box above the list.)*

*From: http://www.strictlyuntyped.com/2010/12/new-ruby-19-hash-syntax.html*

Comment: Consider adding a new snipped called < Hash Pair - key: "value" > with a different trigger, double colon, for example.